# API to publish data from shapefile

Tags: gis, geospatial, shapefile

GIS is not really my expertise and need advice from experts here. Pardon me for my incorrect terms. I have a client asking to develop a system which provides API to consume data from their POI, PA and MPA datasets (in shapefile). Question is, what are my options to do this? Should I develop the system from scratch by maybe converting the shapefile to GeoJSON, or us there any opensource/paid solution already made for this use case? Any help/tip/advice would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org). I know people without GIS or technical knowledge who managed to publish geodata with it on the web. The [vector data / JSON API](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html#json-and-jsonp-output) is an implementation of the OGC WFS standard - which might come handy if later your client decides to plug the data in something like Leaflet or OpenLayers (or most other GIS frameworks for that matter).

Note that GeoServer is a great standalone solution. But I'm not so sure it is your best option if what you are describing is just one part of a more complex system.

Comment: "publish geodata to web", that's pretty much what I need. what do you mean that I probably need more than geoserver? does geoserver provide capability like limiting access to my geodata using API key?

Comment: I can't speak from experience, but it looks like GeoServer has an authkey module.

Comment: "I probably need more than geoserver" - sorry, that was a misunderstanding. What I meant is: If publishing geodata IS the entire system, GeoServer is probably your best shot. If publishing geodata is PART of that system, you might want to look at something a bit leaner, i.e. that's easier to integrate.